# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(1/2-n)(3/2+n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm facing the aforementioned sum, namely

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(1/2-n)(3/2+n)}$$

and even though using mathematica I found it evaluates to $2$, I'm actually wondering what is the quickest way to find that result. Noting it has the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nf(n), \quad f(z):= \frac{1}{(1/2-n)(3/2+n)}$$

I employed the usual method of evaluating the residues of $\pi\csc(\pi z) f(z)$ at $f$'s poles but, halas, the sum of such poles is $0$, so I get

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n}{(1/2-n)(3/2+n)} =\frac{4}{3} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n[f(n) + f(-n)] = 0$$

which is hardly informative given that $f$ is neither even or odd.

I hence wonder what is the proper method to evaluate this sum, since I seem to be doing it wrong or, at least, I don't see how to follow. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{(1/2 - n)(3/2 - n)}}=\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{{2n - 1}} + \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n + 3}}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By partial fractions, the sum is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac1{2n+3}-\frac1{2n-1}\right)$$ Now if $m=2k+1$, with $k\geq1$ then $m=(2k-1)+3=2(k+1)-1$ so that $\frac1m$ occurs in the sum with signs $(-1)^{k-1}$ and $-(-1)^{k+1}$ and so drops out.  However, when $k=0$, then both signs are positive, and the sum is $1+1=2$.

Comment: Certainly this is much more witty than what I was trying. It'd be nice if you could answer a further question: might one find that result using residue analysis? I'm sure it might ask for much more work, but I wonder if there is a way to keep going once we get that the series from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ evaluates to $0$.

Comment: @Hal I don't see how to do it with residues offhand, but that doesn't mean there isn't a way.  I haven't dealt with that stiff in a long time.